# Bypass Xserver display management

Tags: linux, window, x11, xorg, xserver

I am working on an embedded system running a single GUI application. I am using a custom Linux build (buildroot) and have no windowing system installed. The application uses EGL to allocate an on-screen rendering buffer.

I have starting working on supporting keyboard and mouse inputs and would like to use some the input management capabilities that the xserver offers. My understanding is that the xserver drivers are modular and I can load only what is needed (xf86-input-xxx). Is it possible/reasonable to use the xserver for input managment while bypassing the display management aspect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The input events are always routed to an X window. There is no generic "input queue" that you can poll.